# Docker throws two warnings related to cgroup rt period/runtime in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-17.04

When I run `docker &` I get:

```
INFO[0000] libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 3091 
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: aufs 
INFO[0000] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.
```

I also get all these warnings:

```
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (8564990571b56c26f32872031507e77f786b870b27ed3f0b80eebe127ce65164). 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container 8564990571b56c26f32872031507e77f786b870b27ed3f0b80eebe127ce65164 state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/8564990571b56c26f32872031507e77f786b870b27ed3f0b80eebe127ce65164/shm: invalid argument 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (c997c7c33a57163106e3de4c470a5f0e5bd3d030c259e62a9d6ea8c292e3551f). 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container c997c7c33a57163106e3de4c470a5f0e5bd3d030c259e62a9d6ea8c292e3551f state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/c997c7c33a57163106e3de4c470a5f0e5bd3d030c259e62a9d6ea8c292e3551f/shm: invalid argument 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (28c274e176c9c112f8bc73f6916860665c63f1407ca2670944deee7b6ae2e747). 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container 28c274e176c9c112f8bc73f6916860665c63f1407ca2670944deee7b6ae2e747 state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/28c274e176c9c112f8bc73f6916860665c63f1407ca2670944deee7b6ae2e747/shm: invalid argument 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (cca4cbbfb9970b29a26f6cc06622311c0ac789a729810529f35160f742e96c50). 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container cca4cbbfb9970b29a26f6cc06622311c0ac789a729810529f35160f742e96c50 state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/cca4cbbfb9970b29a26f6cc06622311c0ac789a729810529f35160f742e96c50/shm: invalid argument 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (fa2937c2ca6cef38dea9de80b68c9a68497739c391393132870e9c6c295ee72b). 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container fa2937c2ca6cef38dea9de80b68c9a68497739c391393132870e9c6c295ee72b state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/fa2937c2ca6cef38dea9de80b68c9a68497739c391393132870e9c6c295ee72b/shm: invalid argument 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (b8335587ad37a36a35fc2f1eb57b3b3d91f61af75262eb075b9045664885ee30). 
WARN[0000] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container b8335587ad37a36a35fc2f1eb57b3b3d91f61af75262eb075b9045664885ee30 state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0000] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/b8335587ad37a36a35fc2f1eb57b3b3d91f61af75262eb075b9045664885ee30/shm: invalid argument 
WARN[0001] libcontainerd: client is out of sync, restore was called on a fully synced container (40d2418b6741c35dd249d5e4c7aefd248fa6f0efa25d7578f81fff06aea93d3b). 
WARN[0001] libcontainerd: failed to retrieve container 40d2418b6741c35dd249d5e4c7aefd248fa6f0efa25d7578f81fff06aea93d3b state: rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not found 
WARN[0001] failed to cleanup ipc mounts:
failed to umount /var/lib/docker/containers/40d2418b6741c35dd249d5e4c7aefd248fa6f0efa25d7578f81fff06aea93d3b/shm: invalid argument
```

lsb_release -a

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu5-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: I see this, too. I haven't decided whether it's a problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Cgroups features, required by Docker, are not supported by your current kernel. Are you using Debian?
Anyway, these warnings show that no memory, CPU and swap limitations could be applied to Docker containers.
You should update your Kernel if you want/need them.

Answer (score 0):

Had that same issue on Xenial and was about to re-compile the kernel according to docker's needs but did not find any of the switches deactivated in the current config as it claimed to be.
Turned out: once I removed (--purge) all the docker packets including cgroupfs-mount and aufs-tools and installed the very same version of docker again, it worked. Guess it's caused by something in the details of some required packet. Strange enough.